# Pycharm won't happen after installing plugin

Tags: python, plugins, pycharm, ide, robotframework

I have recently been working with Pycharm for Robot Framework and everything was going fine until I decided to get adventurous with one of the plugins. While I was meant to use a Intellibot plugin from a GitHub website,(https://github.com/lte2000/intellibot#intellijpycharm-plugin-for-robot-automation-framework), I decided to try out a Intellibot plugin built into Pycharm as well.

All of a sudden then, Pycharm decides to restart ( thought it was a normal process, as after plugins, it requests to be restarted) but did not restart again. Hence I tried opening it on my own, and all it kept showing was as screenshot attached. Only the loading screen, without ever opening.

[image]

I checked my task manager and it wasn't using any CPU, but was open as a 'background process'

I have also tried running with the cmd, and what shows was a line of errors, like what is in the attached screenshot.

[image]

It looks like the obvious problem to my problems with Pycharm is this plugin, and i was wondering what I could do in order to open Pycharm without a problem.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: While you might be a fan of JetBrains products I would recommend you to to try eclipse with red plugin to see if it fits your needs. I've started using it a while ago when I figured out that RIDE is making too many calls to update the UI on initial project load (which makes things verry slow).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are not using the Toolbox App - remove the offending plugin manually from

```
C:\Users\YOUR_USER\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharm2021.1\plugins
```